# Wilcoxon test problem

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to solve the following (standard) Wilcoxon test problem:

Let $X_i$ be the number of calls received at a call center on the days $i = 1,. . . ,30$ of one
calendar month. The number of calls are, for a given month and in increasing order,

$$1,2,\dots 30$$

The null hypothesis is that the distribution of the number of calls is identical on all
days (so, under $H_0$, the $X_i$ are sampled from the same distribution). There is suspicion,
however, that on the first day of the month, i.e. for $i = 1$, an additional $\Delta > 0$ calls
are to be expected on average. The number of calls received for the given month on day
$i = 1$ is $X_1 = 30$, corresponding to the largest number of calls over all days.

$1)$ Conduct the Wilcoxon test. What is the test statistic? Find the (exact) p-value
and the test result when testing at level $a = 0.05$.

$2)$ Suppose we only suspected that there is some day in $i = 1,. . . ,30$ for which there
are more calls than usual ( and we do not know which day has a surplus of calls).
A first approach to this might be to apply the test above to every day $i = 1,. . . ,30$
in turn. With this approach, will you be able to test whether there is a day for
which there are on average more calls (versus the null hypothesis that all days have
the same distribution of calls)? To answer, consider first how many rejections you
would expect in this setting if, in reality, the distribution of calls is identical on all
days.

$3)$ Suppose that the numbers of calls are monitored for another month with independent
measurements $Y_i, i = 1,. . . ,30$. The suspicion is again that the number of calls is higher
on the first day of the month, e.g. for $i = 1$, by an additional $\Delta > 0$ calls. Let $W_x$
be the Wilcoxon test statistic for the observations $X$ in the first month and $W_y$ is the
Wilcoxon test statistic for the observations $Y$ in the second month of observations.

Let the test statistic $T_{\text{min}}$, be defined as $T_{\text{min}} = \min\{W_y, W_x\}$ . Let $T_{\text{max}}$ be the test
statistic $T_{\text{max}} = \max\{W_x, W_y\}$.
Suppose that both the measurements $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are the largest in their respective
measurement series, so that $X_1 = \max_i X_i$ and $Y_1 = \max_i Y_i$. Conduct an appropriate
test using first $T_{\text{min}}$, as a test statistic and then using $T_{\text{max}}$

**My work:**
So what I did was to perform the Wilcoxon test for the pairs $\{1\dots29\}, \{30
\}$ to get that the p-value is $0.033$ so we reject the null hypothesis that on all of the days, the same number of phone calls are received.

I have a problem in the second part - if we apply the test for all $30$ possible days, than in only one of them we will reject the null hypothesis, i.e. when we have the maximum since $\frac{1}{30}<0.05<\frac{2}{30}$. So the answer seems to be yes. However, I feel like I'm missing something.

Finally, for $(3)$ don't we have that $T_{\text{min}}=T_{\text{max}}=30$ since both of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are the maximal in the respective samples? What's the point of all that?

Any advice/confirmation would be gladly accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2):

(a) Even assuming all months have 30 days (not true), the idea of checking the $i$th day of each month against the other 29 would entail 30 tests altogether. At the 5% level you would expect $30(.05) = 1.5$ rejections. That alone should tell you this is not the greatest approach. Maybe that is the point of the problem.

(b) But that leaves the question whether there is something sensible to do.
I would plot the data and look for monthly periodicities. That's just a graphical approach, but I would want to take a look before going on to formal tests. Perhaps make a $12 \times 30$ matrix, make a boxplot of the means of
its rows, and see if there is a far outlier. If so test the corresponding day
against the others and see if it is significantly different. But by picking
out one day of the month in this way, I wonder what the true significance level would be.

For another way of looking for an unusual day, you might do a chi-squared test of homogeneity, treating the matrix as
a contingency table. If the null hypothesis of homogeneity is rejected,
then look at Pearson residuals to see where the major discrepancies are. 
But I'm not sure this method has good power.

**Addendum:** Here is an experiment in R with fake Poisson counts:

```
x = rpois(12, 50)       # avg 50 calls on first days of months
y = rpois(360-12, 30)   # avg 30 calls on other days
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 4132, p-value = 7.703e-09                               # very highly signif
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

boxplot(x, y, varwidth=T, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")     # thin plot as 12 days
```

[image]

Another experiment with respective Poisson means 50 and 45 is still highly significant
with P-value 0.005768.

Comment: I have $2$ concerns: Firstly, when we perform all $30$ tests, as you said we expect to reject the null $1.5$ times (in fact, we are going to reject it exactly once) - why is that a problem? If we reject it the we have evidence that the day we are testing is the one with the most calls, while we reject it, we can claim that those days aren't the one with the most calls. The second thing is related to a further part of this exam question and I will edit the question to include it. Would be very grateful if you could have a look!

Comment: The problem with getting into a stream of statistical analysis that virtually ensures you will reject _something._ is that you then have little confidence that what it seems may be significant really is. // I will try to look at your edits in the morning.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it

Comment: Unclear whether your 'data' are counts or ranks. For counts of one day of month vs all others, I don't see why the test seems pointless. See expt appended to my answer.

Comment: The data consists of counts, but when we perform the Wilcoxon test we take the ranks don't we? And since both of the objects we are testing (as a single group) are the maximums in the respective sample, then both will have rank $30$ and hence the corresponding statistics will both equal $30$. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the whole story. See addendum to my Answ.

Comment: In your answer you've not taken the first day to take the highest value? I think I am missing something obvious - sorry if I'm wasting your time